# Combining Three 1D arrays into a 2D array?

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, numpy, concatenation

I have three numpy arrays of shape `(250L,)` called `c`, `I` and `error`. I want to be able to save the three arrays to a text file so that each array is one column in the file. So far I have tried the following:

```
DataArray = np.concatenate((c,I,Error),axis=1)
np.savetxt('VaryingC.txt',DataArray)
```

This returns an error since the initial arrays are 1D:

> IndexError: axis 1 out of bounds [0, 1)

How can I combine the three arrays to make a shape `(250,3)` array?

Comment: are you after: `np.column_stack((c,I,Error))`?

Answer (score 3):

`concatenate` joins existing axes, [`stack`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.stack.html) inserts new ones:

```
DataArray = np.stack((c,I,Error),axis=1)
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems you are looking for:

```
DataArray = np.column_stack((c,I,Error))
```

**Timing:**

```
In [201]: a1 = np.random.randint(10**6, size=10**6)

In [202]: a2 = np.random.randint(10**6, size=10**6)

In [203]: a3 = np.random.randint(10**6, size=10**6)

In [204]: %timeit np.column_stack((a1,a2,a3))
100 loops, best of 3: 14.1 ms per loop

In [205]: %timeit np.stack((a1,a2,a3),axis=1)
100 loops, best of 3: 14.2 ms per loop

In [206]: %timeit np.transpose([a1,a2,a3])
100 loops, best of 3: 10.7 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case you could just create a new array and then transpose it:

```
np.transpose([c, I, Error])
```

[`np.transpose`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html) automatically creates a new array, so you don't need to create one yourself.

For example:

```
>>> import numpy as np

>>> a = np.array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
>>> b = np.array([2, 2, 2, 2, 2])
>>> c = np.array([3, 3, 3, 3, 3])

>>> DataArray = np.transpose([a, b, c])
>>> DataArray
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3]])

>>> DataArray.shape
(5, 3)
```

Comment: your solution seems to be the fastest out of the provided ones :)

Comment: @MaxU Thanks for doing the timings! That it's the fastest doesn't surprise me: After all `transpose` is the least general solution. It's worth noting that with `transpose` the result is F-contiguous while `stack` and `column_stack` return C-contiguous arrays.